# Capacitor plugin addListener RxJs style

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, capacitor

I would like to write this:

```js
PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
   console.log('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
});
```

in [RxJs](https://rxjs.dev/) style. I tried using [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEventPattern) but I get:

> ```
> Argument of type 'PushNotificationsPlugin' is not assignable to parameter of type '(handler: NodeEventHandler) => any'.
> ```

EDIT:

I tried with:

```js
register() {
  const addPushNotificationListener = (handler: (token: Token) => void) => {
      PushNotifications.addListener('registration', handler);
  };
  return fromEventPattern(addPushNotificationListener)
    .pipe(
      map((token: Token) => this.token = token)
  );
}
```

But it's not working at all.. the map function is never called.

EDIT II:

Full code:

```js
/** PushNotificationsService */

@Log()
requestPermissionsAndRegister() {
  return this.requestPermissions()
  .pipe(
    filter(permissionGranted => permissionGranted),
    switchMap(() => this.register())
  );
}


@Log()
private requestPermissions(): Observable<boolean> {
  return from(PushNotifications.requestPermissions())
    .pipe(
      map((status: PermissionStatus) => status.receive === 'granted')
    );
}

@Log()
private register() {
  const addPushNotificationListener = (handler) => {
    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', handler);
  };
  return fromEventPattern(addPushNotificationListener)
    .pipe(
      map((token: Token) => this.token = token)
    );
}
```

And from another class:

```js
this.pushNotificationService.requestPermissionsAndRegister()
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: Can you post how you call `fromEventPattern` please?

Comment: Something like this private reg = () => fromEventPattern(PushNotifications.addListener('registration')); but addListener exptects a listenerFunc

Comment: You most probably are sending the wrong handler arguments in `fromEventPatter`. Could you please show the code that threw the error?

Comment: Do you subscribe to the observable you create with `fromEventPattern`?

Comment: Yes, added full code. Everything works except latest map

Answer (score 1):

If I follow the example here [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEventPattern#examples):

```
function addPushNotificationListener(handler) {
  PushNotifications.addListener('registration', handler);
};

const push$ = fromEventPattern(addPushNotificationListener);
```

Of course you should also add a remove handler.

Comment: Please check out my post edit

Answer (score 0):

I was not calling `PushNotifications.register();`, the following code works:

```js
private register() {

  PushNotifications.register();

  const addPushNotificationListener = (handler) => {
    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', handler);
  };
  return fromEventPattern(addPushNotificationListener)
    .pipe(
      map((token: Token) => this.token = token)
    );
}
```